# How do I get rid of this duplicate method error?

Tags: java, constructor

This is my code, I want to fix it so that duplicate method error, I was thinking of doing
"public Color(float h, float s, float v, int a)" as a placeholder, but I'm wondering if there is a better option.

```
private float red;
    private float blue;
    private float green;
    
    public Color( float r, float g, float b){
        red = r;
        blue = b;
        green = g;
    }
    private float hue;
    private float saturation;
    private float value;
    public Color (float h, float s, float v){
        hue = h;
        saturation = s;
        value = v;
    }
```

Comment: You can add a boolean parameter. If it's true, the three floats are RGB values. If it's false, they are HSV values.

Comment: *FYI:* Since they are using entirely different fields, you should have `Color` as an abstract class or as an interface, then have two classes `RgbColor` and `HsvColor`.

Answer (score 2):

If the behaviour of a constructor would be unclear, like it would in this case, you could use a static method to return new objects instead, along with a private constructor.

```
private float red;
private float green;
private float blue;

private Color(float r, float g, float b){
    red = r;
    green = g;
    blue = b;
}

public static Color fromRGB(float r, float g, float b) {
   return new Color(r, g, b);
}

public static Color fromHSV( float h, float s, float v) {
   // Do the mathematics here to convert HSV to RGB, and then use 
   // return new Color(...) on the result
}
```

That way, you can write `Color.fromRGB(10, 10, 10)` (or whatever), instead of `new Color(10, 10, 10)` and the meaning is far clearer.

Comment: Actually, the constructor would be `private Color(float r, float g, float b, float h, float s, float v)`, or maybe just `private Color()` and the two factory methods would set the fields directly. --- Though they really should be 2 different classes, as I [commented in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65413357/how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-duplicate-method-error#comment115648887_65413357). --- Still, +1 from me, since factory methods is the right way to resolve constructor ambiguity like this.

Comment: @Andreas I disagree, about the constructor.  You don't need all six fields.  The mathematics to convert HSV to RGB would go in the second factory method.  I'll expand the answer to make it clearer though.

Comment: But the question specifically shows that class has 6 fields, not 3. If the constructor with HSV arguments is called, the 3 HSV fields are set, and the 3 RGB fields are left unassigned. The class does not convert color model in the constructors. Your answer is now deviating from the requested functionality, without even mentioning it.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, you're right, from a theoretical standpoint, although it's hard for me to accept that that's really what OP wants.  Why don't you post your own answer, using a constructor with six arguments?  Just in case OP really does want their class to have six fields (which to me seems like an odd design for a Color class).

Comment: If you read my first comment, you'd know I suggested splitting the class in two, as a better solution than keeping two sets of fields in one class.

Comment: Yes, I read all your comments.  I'm suggesting you could tie all your comments together into an answer.  It sounds like it might be quite different from mine.